# Swift, string check

Tags: arrays, swift, text

I have to check if a text field string has in it some [String] from the array, but I can only check if the text field is the same of the [String].

```
var array = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

if //textField.text contains some of the words in the array

{  //do something }
```

I start studying swift recently, please help me.

Comment: @CodeDifferent it says: "textField.text contains some of the words in the array" so some of the words in the text field may not be inside the array. I first thought of this too, but I don't think that's what the OP is looking for

Comment: I tried but with this method goes only if text field has only the word in array, I want something like:

Comment: text field: Hello world.  array: world

Comment: if in text field I write something like: Hello everybody, I would like to check if in the array there is the word 'everybody' and then do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple. First make sure to add this before your `class ViewController: UIViewController{}`:

```
import Foundation
```

And then, you can find the number of common words like so:

```
var array = ["word1", "word2", "word3 and word 4"]
var count=0
var s=textField.text!
for item in array{
    if s.components(separatedBy: " ").contains(item){
         count+=1
    }
}
if count > 0{ // do something here
   print("There are \(count) in the text field from the array") 
}
```

And if the array contains elements with spaces, do something like this:

```
var array = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
var count=0
var s=textField.text!
for item in array{
    if s.contains(item){
         count+=1
    }
}
if count > 0{ // do something here
   print("There are \(count) in the text field from the array") 
}
```

### Explanation:

If a word is found, the variable `count` increases by 1. After that, you check if the `count` is higher than 0, and if so, you do what you want there.

---

The final code will look like this:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class myClass: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var array = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]
    var count=0
    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
         var s=textField.text!
         for item in array{
             if s.components(separatedBy: " ").contains(item){
                count+=1
            }
         }
        if count > 0{
            print("There are \(count) in the text field from the array")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have any other questions about this, make sure to ask

Comment: One more thing, if in the array there is something like this?                                   : var array = ["word1", "word2", "other word"].  (string with space like the last one in the array)

Comment: oh, yes. Updating the answer for that case as well

Comment: Thank you a lot for increasing my knowledge

Comment: The pleasure's on my side. Really glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

For such a case, what I suggest is to use [contains(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2297359-contains) method:

```
var array = ["word1", "word2", "word3"]

let isWordExist = array.contains("word1") // that should be true

if array.contains(textField.text!) {
    // array DOES contains the textfield's text
} else {
    // array DOES NOT contains the textfield's text
}
```

**Also**

if you are interested in counting the given string in an array, I would suggest to use the [filter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688383-filter) method, as follows:

```
var array = ["word1", "word1", "Word1", "Word1", "word2", "Word2"]

let numberOfMyWord = array.filter { $0 == "word1" }.count // that should be 2

let numberOfTextFieldText = array.filter { $0 == textField.text! }.count
```

Hope this helped.